# How to write conditional css with changable values

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I have a Card looks like this

```
    <Card.Header style={room.roomCapacity === room.students.length ? {backgroundColor: "#DC4C64"} : room.students.length === 0 ? {backgroundColor: '#14A44D'} : {backgroundColor: '#E4A11B'}} className={"text-center CardHeader"}>{room.roomNumber}</Card.Header>
```

But I want to write all styles in css. So how can i implement style={} function into css with these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a memoization function with [`useMemo`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo) to get the correct color based on your conditions.

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';

const ExampleComponent = ({ room }) => {
  const isRoomFull = room.roomCapacity === room.students.length;
  const isRoomEmpty = room.students.length === 0;

  const backgroundColor = useMemo(() => {
    if (isRoomFull) {
      return '#DC4C64';
    }

    if (isRoomEmpty) {
      return '#14A44D';
    }

    return '#E4A11B';
  }, [isRoomFull, isRoomEmpty]);

  return (
    <Card.Header 
      className="text-center CardHeader"
      style={{
        backgroundColor
      }} 
    >
      {room.roomNumber}
    </Card.Header>
  );
};
```